# How can I make in-container tools like drush or typo3cms usable if they're not in the standard DDEV PATH?

Tags: ddev

I have a nonstandard composer layout, so some of my tools are in docroot/vendor/bin instead of the expected vendor/bin, so they're not in the $PATH inside the web container, and tools like `ddev drush` or `ddev typo3cms` don't work right because they can't find the tool. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of ways to solve this problem. The simplest is probably to just symlink your tool(s) into `/usr/local/bin` where they will easily be found. There are at least a couple of ways to do this. (Note that for most projects, the best long-term solution is to use a standard composer layout with the composer.json in the project root and the vendor directory in the project root, but we all know we can't fix everything. But `vendor/bin` is always in the $PATH.. so that's the usual easiest way to do this.)

1. **Symlink in a post-start hook**: We can add a post-start hook to symlink typo3cms (for example) into /usr/local/bin and `ddev typo3cms` will find the tool. Add something like this to `.ddev/config.yaml`

```yaml
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec: ln -s /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/bin/typo3cms /usr/local/bin
```

2. **Symlink in a `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile`**: To add a symlink to drush, for example, in a nonstandard location and make `ddev drush` work, add this file as `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE

RUN ln -s /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to do this, by manipulating the $PATH inside the container (by adding .bashrc inside the [homeadditions feature](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/in-container-configuration/))